# A stochastic proof, that the sine is an infinite product

Tags: trigonometry, probability-theory

Consider $\Omega = \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N} $. Let $$U(\omega) =\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\omega_i}{2^i} $$ where all $\omega_i \in \{0,1\}$. We can show, that $2U+1$ is uniformly distributed in $[-1,1]$.Therefore we know, that its characteristic function is $$\frac{\sin(t)}{t}.$$

We now want to establish, that sinus is an infinte product. Therefore we have to calculate $$E[e^{it (2U-1)}]$$ in a different way as a infinite product
$$E[e^{it (2U-1)}] = \prod_{i=1}^\infty...$$ How can one do that? Does anyone know the ansatz for that?

Comment: Well, use the fact that the characteristic function of a sum with independent increments is the product of the characteristic functions. After that, you might need the characteristic function of the random variable $X_n$ defined by $X_n(\omega)=2\omega_n-1$ hence you may begin by computing this.

Comment: Eugene Lukacs wrote a book called _Characteristic Functions_ in which, if I recall correctly, you will find this.  But I think Didier Piau's comment pretty much covers it.

Comment: Note, incidentally, that the English name for the $\sin$ function is "(the) sine" rather than "sinus".

Comment: Thanks a lot! With Didier Piau's post it follows by easy computations.

Comment: @Didier: Doesn't that get you [Viète's infinite product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Vi.C3.A8te.27s_infinite_product)? Not sure which infinite product the OP is asking for.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: yes it does!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the fact that the characteristic function of a sum with independent increments is the product of the characteristic functions. After that, you might need the characteristic function of the random variable  $X_n$   defined by $X_n(\omega)=2\omega_n-1$      hence you may begin by computing this.

As mentioned by @Raskolnikov, the result involves [Viète's infinite product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Vi.C3.A8te.27s_infinite_product).